# Manually invalidate Django CMS page cache

Tags: django-cms

From http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/how_to/caching.html I read that caching for Django CMS plugins is always enabled and set to 60s.

In my Django CMS project I have a regular Django view where I update some data and refresh the Django CMS page afterwards.
Due to the CMS plugin cache the page will sometimes show old data.

Because of performance reasons I'd like to keep the cache enabled for reads if no updates have been made but invalidate it in case updates have been made so my CMS views always contain fresh data.

Is it possible to manually clear the cms plugin cache inside an update view modifying the database? Maybe if I know the cache key that Django CMS is using for my plugin - how can I find out this key?

Comment: Hello, django CMS does not have plugin level caching. Instead there's page and placeholder cache. Please check in your settings which one (if any or both) is configured.

Comment: @Paulo Ok got it, so then how can I invalidate the page cache for my page manually?

Comment: It has plugin level caching http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/reference/configuration.html#std:setting-CMS_PAGE_CACHE